# Generic type which isn't of an interface type

Tags: go, generics

I'm trying to work with generics to create a [parameterised type](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_parameter_declarations) which can be of:

```
T, *T, T[], map[interface{}]interface{}
```

Where: `T` is of `comparable` type, but ***is not** an interface*.

---

I've attempted to formulate this through constrained typeset, but this fails due to [MisplacedTypeParam](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools/internal/typesinternal#MisplacedTypeParam:%7E:text=//%20MisplacedTypeParam%20occurs%20when%20a%20type%20parameter%20is%20used%20in%20a%20place%20where%0A%09//%20it%20is%20not%20permitted.) compiler error:

```
type myType[T comparable] interface {
    T | *T | T[] | map[interface{}]interface{}
}
```

I also have the issue when using `reflect`, that getting the `reflect.Kind`
or `reflect.Type` of an interface will return the value's type underlying the interface, which means I haven't figured out how to assert the type ***is not** an interface*.

---

From this, I am wondering what the best alternative way to represent such a type would be?

---

This is my work in progress (https://github.com/mcwalrus/go-jitjson) and its main parts:

```
type JitJSON[T any] struct {
    data []byte
    val  *T
}

func (jit *JitJSON[T]) Unmarshal() (T, error) {
    if jit.val != nil {
        return *jit.val, nil
    }

    var val T
    if jit.data == nil {
        return val, nil
    }

    jit.val = &val
    err := json.Unmarshal(jit.data, jit.val)
    if err != nil {
        return val, err
    }

    return *jit.val, nil
}
```

Comment: It seems so far that generic types will not provide a complete solution here. For polymorphism to make sense, you must define some common behaviour across the disparate types. What is the common behaviour you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Yeah that was the conclusion I reached as well. I understand that polymorphic constraint, although this didn't seem intuitive when first approaching generics.

Comment: The solution is to be used for a 'just-in-time json' parsing struct. I have been aiming to make the parser generically parameterised if possible.

Comment: I'm not quite envisioning how this would work. Maybe you could include some example/hypothetical snippets of how this parsing system would be used in code.

Comment: I have a work-in-progress version here: https://github.com/mcwalrus/go-jitjson

Comment: Thanks @blackgreen, I hadn't realised comparable excludes interfaces already. I'll edit my question in response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot** implement this simply as a type constraint. Therefore, you must rely on run-time checks.

You may implement the type check through `reflect`, but this may be redundant in your application, as the standard library `json` already produces an appropriate error when trying to marshal or unmarshal an incompatible data type.

If you do want to use `reflect` to inspect the exact type of a parameterized type, here's the naive but incorrect way to do it:

```golang
func f[T any]() {
    var zero T
    typ := reflect.TypeOf(zero)
    fmt.Println(typ)
}
```

This works for *most* types, except for interface types, for which it will always report `typ` as `<nil>`. This is because of how assignment of interface values works in Go. Here is the **correct** way to do it:

```golang
func f[T any]() {
    var zero T
    typ := reflect.TypeOf(&zero).Elem()
    fmt.Println(typ)
}
```

This is necessary because interface values, at runtime, only carry type information of the *concrete type* which they reference. By taking the pointer to an interface variable, taking the type of the pointer, then taking the element of the pointer type, the actual type of the interface variable can be extracted.

---

** I can't seem to find a concise explanation of why this can't be done, but here are some difficulties:

- `comparable` cannot be used in a type union
- type constraints cannot be composed
- type constraints cannot be defined recursively
- type constraints cannot be negated
- there is no interface which matches structs in general

Answer (score 0):

As of Go 1.19 the constraint `comparable` already can be implemented only by **strictly comparable** types, i.e. types for which `==` and `!=` are guaranteed to not panic at run time.

So this does exclude interfaces. However it also excludes other types that aren't strictly comparable but also not interfaces either, e.g. `[5]any` or `struct{ Data any }`.

I don't know if this is good enough for you. Otherwise, there is no way to define a constraint type set in terms of subtractions, i.e. in set notation, A \ B. From the spec:

> An interface type is specified by a list of interface elements. An interface element is either a method **or a type element, where a type element is a union of one or more type terms.** A type term is either a single type or a single underlying type.

If you need to exclude some [kinds](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#Kind) of types from your computation you might have to fall back to reflection.
Consider also that if your goal is to unmarshal JSON, using `any` constraint and `*T` might be acceptable (`==` checks if two pointers point to the same variable). After all, *you are supposed to* pass an addressable value to `json.Unmarshal`:

```
// code simplified for illustrative purposes
func (jit *JitJSON[T]) Unmarshal() (T, error) {
    var val T
    err := json.Unmarshal(jit.data, &val) // needs a pointer anyway
    if err != nil {
        return val, err
    }
    jit.val = &val
    return *jit.val, nil
}
```